# Does the fetch API handle __proto__ differently to assigning it?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

When I'm using fetch to get a payload which has a `__proto__` set it seems to not apply this to the Object prototype in the same way that assigning to a object would do.

This is good as it means that Object prototype will never get polluted by an API call, but I'm a bit confused as to why/how this works?

For example, if I have a `payload.json`:

```
{
  "__proto__": { "toString": "foobar" }
}
```

and fetch this:

```
 fetch("payload.json")
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(json) {
        // JSON from a fetch payload
        console.log("--JSON from a fetch payload--");
        console.log("payload.toString():", json.toString()); // [object Object]
        console.log("json.__proto__:", json.__proto__); // {toString: "foobar"}
        console.log("{}.toString()", {}.toString()); //[object Object]

        //New object with __proto__ set
        console.log("--New object with __proto__ set--");
        const x = { __proto__: { toString: () => "hacked" } };
        console.log("x.toString(): ", x.toString());
        console.log("{}.toString(): ", {}.toString());
        console.log(
          "JSON.parse('{}').toString(): ",
          JSON.parse("{}").toString()
        );

        // Set proto with assignment
        console.log("--Set proto with assignment--");
        const y = {};
        y.__proto__.toString = () => "polluted";
        console.log("y.toString(): ", y.toString());
        console.log("x.toString(): ", x.toString());
        console.log("{}.toString(): ", {}.toString());
        console.log(
          "JSON.parse('{}').toString(): ",
          JSON.parse("{}").toString()
        );
      });
```

You get the output:

```
--JSON from a fetch payload-- 
payload.toString(): [object Object] 
json.__proto__: 
Object {toString: "foobar"}
{}.toString() [object Object] 
--New object with __proto__ set-- 
x.toString():  *** hacked *** 
{}.toString():  [object Object] 
JSON.parse('{}').toString():  [object Object] 
--Set proto with assignment-- 
y.toString():  *** polluted *** 
x.toString():  *** hacked *** 
{}.toString():  *** polluted *** 
JSON.parse('{}').toString():  *** polluted ***
```

I understand why the last example pollutes the object prototype, but why is `json.__proto__` being handled differently when coming from an fetch api call?

The example above can be seen on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-noether-l3z3s?file=/index.html)

Comment: It's the same what `JSON.parse('{"__proto__": {}}')` does

Comment: You can create such objects on your own with `const o = Object.create(null); o.__proto__ = {}` or `const o = {}; Object.defineProperty(o, "__proto__", {value: {}, enumerable: true, configurable: true})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this has nothing to do with the `fetch` API.

`__proto__` is a getter/setter property on `Object.prototype`, that turns `[[Get]]` and `[[Set]]` operations into `[[GetPrototypeOf]]` and `[[SetPrototypeOf]]`, respectively.

When you `fetch` the data and parse it as JSON, it behaves the same as `JSON.parse`: Parses the JSON, then creates an empty JS object, and puts the properties on it.

However, they `[[Define]]` the properties instead of `[[Set]]`-ting them, therefore they **won't trigger the setter, and the result ends up having a regular property called `__proto__` pointing to a different object that its `[[Prototype]]`:**

Take a look at the following example:

```js
//Using [[Set]], the way you thought of
const obj1 = {}
obj1.__proto__ = {}
console.log(obj1.hasOwnProperty('__proto__')) //false, because it's inherited
console.log(obj1.__proto__ === Object.getPrototypeOf(obj1)) //true

//Using [[Define]], the way how JSON.parse does it
const obj2 = {}
Object.defineProperty(obj2, '__proto__', {
  value: {},
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true,
  writable: true
})
console.log(obj2.hasOwnProperty('__proto__') //true, it is own
console.log(obj.__proto__ === Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)) //false
```